# HTML table jQuery: determining which column has been clicked when a cell is clicked if the TH has a unique data attribute value

Tags: jquery, html-table, custom-data-attribute

If a table is defined so:

```
            <colgroup>
             <col style="width:100px;">
             <col style="width:100px;">
            </colgroup>
            <thead>
             <th class="foo" data-info="zipcode10023">
             <th class="foo" data-info="zipcode60602">
            </thead>
```

such that the value in custom attribute `data-info` is *unique*, when a cell in the table has been clicked, what is the most efficient way to determine which column has been clicked (i.e. in order to get the data-info value, e.g. "zipcode60606") ?

EDIT:  there may be invisible columns to the left of the clicked-on cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the click is detected on a cell:

```
$('td').click(function(){
    var col = $(this).index(),
        dataInfo = $('thead th').eq(col).attr('data-info');
        /* or:
        dataInfo = $('thead th').eq($(this).index()).attr('data-info');
           or:
        dataInfo = $('thead th').eq($(this).index()).data('info');
        */
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo using: `$('thead th').eq(col).attr('data-info')`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/HAAZu/5/).

[JS Fiddle demo using: `$('thead th').eq($(this).index()).attr('data-info')`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/HAAZu/6/).

[JS Fiddle demo using: `$('thead th').eq($(this).index()).data('info')`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/HAAZu/7/).

You could, of course, place the event-handler on an ancestor element, such as the `tr`, with either:

```
$('tr').click(function (e) {
    var dataInfo = $('thead th').eq(e.target.cellIndex).data('info');
    console.log(dataInfo);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/HAAZu/3/).

(Note that, ordinarily, `event.target` isn't necessarily cross-browser compatible, and Internet Explorer may require (outside of jQuery) an alternative: `window.event.srcElement`, however jQuery normalizes the events, so that not only will IE read/'understand' the `event` (and not require `window.event` instead) but it will also have access to the normalzed `event.target`.)

Or, [to use enough jQuery](http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif):

```
$('tr').on('click', 'td', function (e) {
    var dataInfo = $('thead th').eq($(this).index()).data('info');
    console.log(dataInfo);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/HAAZu/4/).

In much the same way the `click` can also be bound to the `table` element:

```
$('table').click(function (e) {
    var dataInfo = $('thead th').eq(e.target.cellIndex).data('info');
    console.log(dataInfo);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/HAAZu/8/).

References:

- [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).
- [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
- [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/).
- [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).
- [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/).
- [jQuery `event` object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: @Tim: you're very welcome, and I'm glad to have been of help. =)

Comment: I'm not sure yet if the issue is with my table, jQuery, or the definition of cellIndex, but if there are invisible columns to the left of the clicked cell, the code doesn't work as hoped, though it may very well work as it should. cellIndex is visible-columns-based. I will edit my question.

Comment: Then show that in the code you provide, show a demo that accurately recreates and reproduces your actual problem. Show relevant JS and CSS. Help us to help you.

Comment: it's actually a design issue with the UI library I'm working with -- it splits the header and body into separate tables, and when the header column is hidden with display:none, the body table doesn't even include the corresponding column. So your answer is good for a normal HTML table.

Comment: Any chance you could give a sample of the likely mark-up? Perhaps a [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: I will try to add a JS Fiddle later today--hoping to get a prototype into users' hands by this afternoon. In the meantime, it's (very) basically this: `<div><table></table></div> <div><table></table></div>` where the first table contains the header and the second table contains the content-body. See Kendo UI.